# SonarQube is not taking code coverage report generated

Tags: c#, sonarqube, azure-devops

I have added an extension of SonarQube in Visual Studio Team Service(VSTS) and configured with the SonarQube server that I hosted in VM. My .Net core 2.0 application I added the reference to coverlet for code coverage and in VSTS I can see in build dashboard that code coverage (number of lines covered shows). But not in SonarQube platform( means in the server of SonarQube that I hosted). I checked in Agent of VSTS the files .trx are getting created and also the coverage result files are also there but why is the code coverage not getting populated in SonarQube platform that I integrated with VSTS.

Please don’t give solutions of Visual studio IDE, as I am asking about Visual Studio Team Services.

Any help will be fine.

I am using SonarQube Community Edition that I have hosted in Azure virtual machine and using it’s endpoint in Visual Studio Team Service.

Version of SonarQube Scanner that I checked in log : SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0.1227 and SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.3.1

I checked this stackoverflow topic asked too :
[VSTS SonarQube cannot find TRX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019110/vsts-sonarqube-cannot-find-trx-file?rq=1)

It also did not help. Please don't mark my topic asked as duplicate as I tried all the related topics in stackoverflow and other websites.

Comment: Are you passing cc report to sonar?

Comment: Resolved it there was an issue with task I did not set. DotNet restore task I forgot to add and also sonar.cs.coverage.reportPaths I did not set. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it there was an issue with task I did not set. DotNet restore task I forgot to add and also sonar.cs.coverage.reportPaths I did not set.